# Map Scale No Longer working

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I am not sure what happened between where I was working last week and what I am seeing this week. It may be that QGIS updated without my knowledge, but I am not sure because I think the version is still the same though I have seen some things that I thought look different.

I had enabled the OpenLayers Plugin (using Google Streets) and was using a scale of 1:186. There is also a georeferenced image file layer over the Google street layer. I am now unable to see the Google street layer at the scale I had been mapping streets and other points from my image file (there is enough overlap to track changes to the city I am studying). In addition, everything seems skewed slightly to the left, or up, or down from where I had it at the 1:186 scale.

I am not sure what the issue is I need to fix here. Does anyone have any advice or tips?

Comment: Try using the **QuickMapServices** plugin instead =)